# ObjectLiteral type? that extends an object that can take optional and non-optional properties

Tags: typescript

I have this

```js
type ObjectLiteral = Record<string, unknown>

type RunFunction = (args: ObjectLiteral) => void

const execute: RunFunction = (args: { names: string[] }) => {
  console.log(args)
}
```

doing `args` as `{ names: string[] }` doesnt work,
and i get
Error: `Property 'names' is missing in type 'ObjectLiteral' but required in type '{ names: string[]; }'.`

but making `args` as `{ names?: string[] }` works.

```js
const execute1: RunFunction = (args: { names?: string[] }) => {
  console.log(args)
}
```

I want `args` to extend an 'object literal' that can take both optional and non-optional properties.

so I can do this:

```js
const execute2: RunFunction = (args: { names: string[], options?: string[] }) => {
  console.log(args)
}
```

I don't understand what should the type `ObjectLiteral` be.

But doesn't `{ names: string[] }` extend `Record<string, unknown>` ?

Typescript Playground: https://tsplay.dev/N5Pddw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of the `args` in your function implemenation.

You're typing your function to be of type `RunFunction`, which is designed to accept `args` of type `ObjectLiteral`. Type-wise, this `args` can be anything, as long as it conforms to `Record<string, unknown>`.

So it's a problem of mixed messages:

- Your type definition says: `args` can be any type of object literal.
- Your implementation says: `args` can not be any type of object literal. It has to have a property `names` of type `string[]`.

So you have to make up your mind: if your `args` is guaranteed to have a `names` property, then change your type definition. If that's not guaranteed, then don't destructure `args` and implement a check in your method body to see if `names` is present.

There are many other ways to create additional types to support various scenarios, but it's not possible to make any recommendation here because it's unclear why you're doing the destructuring to begin with.

Comment: ahh ok tyvm i understand now